# Saving multiple raster sums to one Excel file on QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have a couple hundred raster files that I want to find the sum for in order to perform some further calculation. I want to have the sum of each raster file placed in one Excel sheet.

[image]

I used to work on ArcGIS, so usually I would just use Model Builder to iterate the procedure, then save it all to an attribute table and export to CSV.

But now I no longer have access to ArcGIS, and I realized that you can't iterate in the QGIS graphical modeler.
Is there a simple way to do this? I would prefer doing it without any scripting or code, because I just need to get this done quickly, but if it's absolutely necessary I don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

In case you won't get any luck with QGIS modeller, you can run this script with QGIS python console:

[image]

The script:

```py
from os import listdir

import processing

rast_dir='/raster/directory/'

ext_tpl=('tif','TIFF','TIF') #change if there are other raster formats in your directory

rast_lst=[fl for fl in listdir(rast_dir) if fl.endswith(ext_tpl)]

out_fl='outputfiledir/outputfile.csv'

with open(out_fl,'w') as fl:
    fl.write('raster_name,sum\n')
    for rast in rast_lst:
        
        res=processing.run("native:rasterlayerstatistics",
                            {'INPUT':rast_dir+rast,'BAND':1})
        rast_sum=res['SUM']
        fl.write(f'{rast},{rast_sum}\n')
```

Comment: @BERA yes, in case if extension is 'tif', or `rast_lst=[fl for fl in listdir(rast_dir) if fl.endswith(('tif','TIFF','TIF'))]` can be used, or any other tuple with extension, I'll edit the answer, thank you

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: I'd like to ask another question, is there any way to do the same thing but for mean instead of sum.
I tried using res['MEAN'] instead of rast_mean=res['SUM'] but i don't think that exists...

Comment: @Ismail hm, `res["MEAN"]` works fine for me. here's all the parameters available from my example: `{'MAX': 148.0, 'MEAN': 71.44134233153648, 'MIN': 0.0, 'RANGE': 148.0, 'STD_DEV': 50.53710384890273, 'SUM': 4347348635.0, 'SUM_OF_SQUARES': 155415938959.4372}`

Comment: Ah yes it works, I just got a wierd error message but the excel file came out as i wanted it to